# How to capture text from html div element with role="alert" using htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit and trying to capture the payment reference number string from html div element which has role="alert". Code I am using is

```
String paymentRefNoFeedbackResponse = paymentRefNoHtmlPage.getByXPath("//div[@class='greenbg']").toString();
```

Output I am getting is

```
[HtmlDivision[<div role="alert" class="greenbg">]]
```

as a result, not the text that appears in the screenshot of inspector attached here with. Can somebody suggest me how to capture the String of text from this kind of div element? What am I doing wrong here?

I am stuck here completely.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the content like this:

```
DomElement element = paymentRefNoHtmlPage.getFirstByXPath("//div[@class='greenbg']");
final String paymentRefNoFeedbackResponse = element.getChildNodes().get(0).getNodeValue();
```

Or you could try with:

```
final String paymentRefNoFeedbackResponse = element.getTextContent();
```

Comment: DomElement element = paymentRefNoHtmlPage.getByXPath("//div[@class='greenbg']"); IDE gives incompatible types error. Can you please suggest some other method?

Comment: @AbsoluteDev I've edited the answer, please try again

Comment: It worked by using .getFirstByXPath.().  Awesome! Many thanks @Villat

Comment: Glad to help @AbsoluteDev!